# Referencing Array items across MVC program (JavaFX application)

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, model-view-controller, subclass

This is my first question on StackOverflow and I thank anyone who can help in advance. I am trying to complete a javaFX application using the Model View Controller design pattern. My application is a true/false quiz ran through a JavaFX GUI. I placed my Model class inside Main (as a subclass) and am not sure if this is proper convention. In any case my class Model reads:

```
public static class Model{

        String question;
        Boolean answer;


        Model(String question, Boolean answer) {
            this.question = question;
            this.answer = answer;
        }

        private static String q1 = 
        private static String q2  //......String values omitted to make post easier to read.......
        private static String q15 = 

        private static Boolean a1 = //.......Boolean values omitted....
        private static Boolean a15 = true;


        private static Model[] questions = { //this is the array I want to reference in Controller
                new Model(q1, a1),
                new Model(q2, a2),
                new Model(q3, a3),
                new Model(q4, a4),
                new Model(q5, a5),
                new Model(q6, a6),
                new Model(q7, a7),
                new Model(q8, a8),
                new Model(q9, a9),
                new Model(q10, a10),
                new Model(q11, a11),
                new Model(q12, a12),
                new Model(q13, a13),
                new Model(q14, a14),
                new Model(q15, a15)
        };

        public static Model[] getQuestions() {
            return questions;
        }
    }

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private Label testReadOut;
    private Button respondTrue;
    private Button respondFalse;
    private boolean start = true;   //not used in my code, from a tutorial, might be needed later 
    private Main.Model[]  questions = Main.Model.getQuestions();

    @FXML
    public void takeTest(ActionEvent event) {
        int score = 0;
        for (int i =0; i<questions.length ; i++) {
!!!         testReadOut.setText(questions.question);  //question is an unresolved symbol
            boolean userAnswer = Boolean.valueOf(((Button)event.getSource()).getText());
!!!         if (userAnswer == questions.answer) {     //answer is an unresolved symbol
                score++;
            }
        }
        testReadOut.setText("User scored: " + score + " out of 15 possible correct answers.");
    }


}

The imports used in Controller are:
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
```

As I indicated with !!! at the start of the rows which prevent compilation, when I create the Model[] named questions in Controller using a getter which returns the desired Model[] from Model (subclass of Main), the references to Model[] attributes are not recognized by the compiler.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/sedj601/QuestionGameWithSQLite/tree/master/src/questongamewithsqlite) can help you.

Comment: `questions` is an array. Arrays don't provide the members you're trying to access. You need to access an element from the array instead (probably `questions[i]`)... No comment on the design btw. I don't have enough time right now...

Answer (score 0):

Use;

```
private static Model[] questions = { //this is the array I want to reference in Controller
            new Model(q1, a1),
            new Model(q2, a2),
            new Model(q3, a3),
            new Model(q4, a4),
            new Model(q5, a5),
            new Model(q6, a6),
            new Model(q7, a7),
            new Model(q8, a8),
            new Model(q9, a9),
            new Model(q10, a10),
            new Model(q11, a11),
            new Model(q12, a12),
            new Model(q13, a13),
            new Model(q14, a14),
            new Model(q15, a15)
    };
```

in the controller class. What I'm saying is create questions array in the controller class.